# Android how to restore content back to /data/data

Tags: android, database, command, command-prompt, database-restore

I am developing an application for rooted phones which will backup and restore all apps and their data. After restoring any app's data to /data/data/{packageName} when I open that app, it crashes with exception **android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database** as I have copied that app's database files into /data/data/{packageName} directory.

The code I use to restore data:

```
String packageName = app.getPackageName();
File destinationFile = new File("/data/data/"+packageName);
File sourceFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"MyBackup"+File.separator+packageName);

String command = "cp -r "+sourceFile.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"* " + destinationFile.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator;
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", command});
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can anybody please tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you also have to set appropriate permissions and owners (`chown` and `chmod`) of those files and directories in `/data/`.

Comment: Ohh right. I should set file permissions too. But can you tell me how? I tried it **[this way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14559068/840669)** but I am failing.