# How to set rw- r-- r-- permissions programmatically?

Tags: android, file-permissions

I am developing an application that can restore apps' data back to /data/data/{packageName}. After restoring the files, I am setting the permissions to rw- r-- r--. I set it in this way:

```
public int chmod(File path, int mode) throws Exception {
    Class fileUtils = Class.forName("android.os.FileUtils");
    Method setPermissions = fileUtils.getMethod("setPermissions",
            String.class, int.class, int.class, int.class);
    return (Integer) setPermissions.invoke(null, path.getAbsolutePath(),
            mode, -1, -1);
}
```

and calling `chmod(file, 644);`

But when I check these files' permissions in file explorer it shows me "--- rwx r-x".

So how can I set the permissions to rw- r-- r--?

Comment: I think you need superuser access to do so

Comment: Yes. I've already got SU access.

String cmd = "cp -r " + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath() + "/* "
    + destinationFile.getAbsolutePath() + "/";

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", cmd });

chmod(destinationFile, 644);

Comment: @Rajkiran I also want to change the permission of a file, and while searching I came to your question. I tried the same code but I wasn't able to find the `FileUtils` class in `android.os` package. How did you used it?? Please answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25397417/3837191).

Comment: What did you really search for? android.os package has a file with that name. Source code : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.1_r1/android/os/FileUtils.java?av=f

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Process process = null;
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

try {
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("chmod 644 FilePath\n");
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
    dataOutputStream.flush();
    process.waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
} finally {
    try {
        if (dataOutputStream != null) {
            dataOutputStream.close();
        }
        process.destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The value is wrong, the correct one is 420 (420 decimal is 644 octal). Alternatively you can add a leading `0` to make it a java octal literal.
i.e.

```
chmod(destinationFile, 0644)
```

Comment: Ohh thanks. But as you can see in my second comment, I am using commands to copy files in SU mode. So I'll go with @android_test for the answer. Anyways, upvoted. :)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to set these permissions (rw- r-- r--) on the file using:

```
path.setReadOnly(true); //Sets all permissions for every owner back to read-only
path.setWritable(true); //Sets the owner's permissions to writeable
```

where `path` is your [File](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) object.

You shouldn't need to use FileUtils with reflection to set permissions on a file.
You can just use the helper methods on the [File](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) class.
With File, you can also call: [setReadable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setReadable(boolean,%20boolean)), [setWritable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setWritable(boolean,%20boolean)), and [setExecutable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setExecutable(boolean,%20boolean))