# Execute chmod programmatically

Tags: android, root

I have a rooted device and I want to change the permission to the folder 'com.android.mms'. My app is system app. Is there a way to do it? 
I have already tried using process and checked this link as well.
[How to get File Permission Mode programmatically in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408154/how-to-get-file-permission-mode-programmatically-in-java)

They don't throw any error but doesn't do the job as well. Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559068/android-how-to-set-rw-r-r-permissions-programmatically

Comment: You cannot use standard Java APIs for file manipulation. Being on a rooted device does not mean you are running as root (you are not). It generally means there is a "su" command which you can invoke in order to perform shell commands as root. The link @ZohraKhan provided has an example of doing that.

Comment: I have seen that link. This works fine if the file is in my package but here I want to manipulate 'com.android.mms' package.

Comment: Probably it is not working for you as your device lacks a hacked su, or has one that works differently.  The stock Android one will not work for this.